# Is google sheet's importxml function broken?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to make an automatically updating google spreadsheet that contained a makeshift BF4 leaderboard to share with friends on Battlelog. I watched a few tutorials on webscraping with `importxml`, which seemed simple enough, however my sheet always returns "imported content is empty".

url: `"https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/BigE1293/awards/960112410/pc/#m39"`

I wanted to get the number of marksman ribbons(image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYGMU.png) my account has from this page so I inspected the element and copied the xpath: `"//*[@id='awards-statistics']/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[5]/div[2]/span"`

I also tried manually writing the xpath: `"//div[@id='award-statistics']//li[5]/div[2]/span"`

Both cases returned the same "imported content is empty" error.

Comment: "...my account has..." - IMPORTXML cant access data behind login pages (if that data is not public). also note that IMPORTXML cant work with javascript content which in your case this is fully JS site

Comment: The content is public. How would I auto update a google spreadsheet for a fully JS site then? All the results I see use IMPORTXML.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem. Nothing is loaded into the battlelog website when I disable JS